# Why does it say exit status 1?

Tags: python, pygame

I want the code to work. So that I can get a good grade of it. I have tried a lot of things so that the code can work event.

```
import pygame.sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((500,400),0,32)
pygame.disply .set_caption(AMBERMIR)

WHITE=(255,255,255)
BLUE=(0,0,255)

DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)

pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,BLUE,(200,150,100,50))

if event.type == QUIT:
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've to implement a main loop which is continuously running. Inside the main loop, an event loop can be handle the events.
Use [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get) to get and remove all pending events from the loop. The return value of `pygame.event.get()` is a list of [`pygame.event.Event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.Event) objects.
After drawing the scene, the window has to be updated by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip):

```py
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

AMBERMIR = "my window"
DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((500,400),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption(AMBERMIR)

WHITE=(255,255,255)
BLUE=(0,0,255)

# main loop
run = True
while run:

    # event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            run = False # terminate main loop on QUIT

    # clear display 
    DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)

    # draw rectangle
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,BLUE,(200,150,100,50))

    # update display
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for you help